# How to open the backup file which created by backup-each-save.el in dired like dired-jump?

Tags: emacs, backup

**Notice:** See my answer before answering this question, because I answered for this question first. But another way or any suggestion are welcomed.

How to open the most recent backup file which created by `backup-each-save.el`  in `dired` like `dired-jump`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm and the code for it.

**Algorithm:**

```
 1. Get the backup directory of the file connected to current opening file buffer.
 2. Open the backup directory.
 3. In the dired buffer, go to end of the buffer.
 4. Search backward for the basename of opening file.
```

---

**Code:**

```
(defun backup-each-save-dired-jump ()
  (interactive)
  (let* (
         (filename (buffer-file-name))
         (containing-dir (file-name-directory filename))
         (basename (file-name-nondirectory filename))
         (backup-container
          (format "%s/%s"
                  backup-each-save-mirror-location
                  containing-dir))
         )
    (when (file-exists-p backup-container)
      (find-file backup-container)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (search-backward basename)
      )))
```

---